# Set Label is not working in Bar Chart using MPAndroid Library

Tags: java, android, char, mpandroidchart

[image]I am using MPAndroid library.
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
I need to create BarChart with labels.
My code is bellow but it's not working:
This is array of bar to display.

```
public ArrayList<BarEntry> getBarEntryArrayList() {

    ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(2f, 0));
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(4f, 1));
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(6f, 2));
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(8f, 3));
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(7f, 4));
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(3f, 5));
    return barEntries;

}
```

This is label array to display at bottom.

```
public ArrayList<String> getBarEntryLabels() {

    ArrayList<String> BarEntryLabels = new ArrayList<String>();
    BarEntryLabels.add("J");
    BarEntryLabels.add("F");
    BarEntryLabels.add("M");
    BarEntryLabels.add("A");
    BarEntryLabels.add("M");
    BarEntryLabels.add("J");
    BarEntryLabels.add("J");
    BarEntryLabels.add("A");
    BarEntryLabels.add("S");
    BarEntryLabels.add("O");
    BarEntryLabels.add("N");
    BarEntryLabels.add("D");
    return BarEntryLabels;

}
```

Problem to set labels array and entry array

```
private void setBarChartData() {
    BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(getBarEntryArrayList(), getBarEntryLabels() );
    barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
    BarData barData = new BarData(barDataSet);
    barChart.setData(barData);
    barChart.animateY(3000);

}
```

This line is not working.

```
BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(getBarEntryArrayList(), getBarEntryLabels() );
```

If make code without labels it's working.

```
BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(getBarEntryArrayList(), "Dummy text" );
```

I have to use array of lables.
Thanks in advance.

I need to created graph like this.
Please help me.

Comment: Buddy you want labels on xAxis or as values on bars above bars or inside bars ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create bar entries, add the label as third parameter:

```
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(2f, 0, "J"));
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(4f, 1, "F"));
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(6f, 2, "M"));
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(8f, 3, "A"));
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(7f, 4, "M"));
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(3f, 5, "P"));
```

After `barChart.setData(barData);` you can set Labels above or below bars with `setValueFormatter`:

```
    barChart.getBarData().setValueFormatter(new IValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
            return entry.getData().toString();
        }
    });
```

Also increase font size:

```
barChart.getData().setValueTextSize(15);
```

P.S. you don't need `getBarEntryLabels` method.

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: It is supported in `3.0.3` version, test project and screen was made with newest version of the library.

Comment: Oh sorry mate I am sorry I tried this but didnt work. May be I did something wrong. I take my words back buddy :)

Comment: But the user want to show labels on xAxis not as values above the bars as I understand.

Comment: I was talking in that context you are right but there is confusion in two concepts. So lets ask original poster what he actually wants :)

Comment: No problem ;)  The main idea here is using  `setValueFormatter`. For mapping values it is better to put Labels in BarEntry object as third parameter. He can do it at top, bottom, X axis etc. wherever user likes. It is not stated clearly where labels should be shown

Answer (score 3):

You need to do following:

```
barChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(BarEntryLabels));
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Do let me know for further assistance. I worked alot using this library. Best of luck mate :)

Comment: Worked for me, but this link helped understand how to do all the code: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/3380

Answer (score 2):

You can set it as following way,

In Kotlin,

```
val xAxis = chart.xAxis
xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(labels)
```

If you are still facing issue, make sure you have not hidden x-Axis. If you'll hide x-Axis, label will not be shown. If you want x-Axis hidden then, you have to make x-Axis visible and give it a transparent color.